# PHP: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): doesn't permit & in a url

Tags: php, domdocument, html-entities

We're trying to use DOMDocument to modify some HTML, but when it hits image/link URL's with '&' it throws an error:

```php
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line xyz
```

Thing is, it's not an entity, but a completely valid URL, and said third party websites **do not accept `&amp;`** as an equivalent in their URLs.

Is there a way, other than hacks using regex and re-encoding and decoding the & several times, to get DOMDocument to not crap itself on those URLs? `libxml_use_internal_errors()` doesn't seem like a good solution as we do need valid HTML output in the end, and there seems to be no docs on how this can effect what it outputs.